# debug va_list args with GDB

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, variadic-functions

I tried to debug Va_list argument and print the variable value sample code is :

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
double average(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    double sum = 0;
    va_start(ap, count); /* Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address) */
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        sum += va_arg(ap, int); /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return sum / count;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%f\n", average(3, 1, 2, 3) );
    return 0;
}
```

so i tried to debug ap va_list argument and i wrote

```
   (gdb) p *(int *)(((char *)ap[0].reg_save_area)+ap[0].gp_offset)
```

but i get as result from GDB

```
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.
```

here is an image for the result:
[image]

Comment: Operator precedence?

Comment: It looks like gcc on Ubuntu 16.04  is not fully entering the type of `ap` into the executable's debuginfo section. It says it's a `va_list`, which is a `__gnuc_va_list`, but doesn't include any other info for `__gnuc_va_list`. Works OK with the default version of clang on 16.04.

Comment: so what can i do to compile with clang?

Comment: yep thanks i compile it with clang and it work

Comment: FWIW it worked for me on Fedora 24.  One way to debug this kind of problem is to pick apart the expression and then `ptype` each element; eventually you'll find something weird, which you can then trace back to the debuginfo if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

When you stopped at line 8 in gdb, this line of code was not yet executed:

```
va_start(ap, count); /* Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address) */
```

Therefore `ap` variable was not yet initialized and you can't print it. You should execute next line of code and print `ap` once again:

```
(gdb) n
9       for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
(gdb) p *(int *)(((char *)ap[0].reg_save_area)+ap[0].gp_offset)
$1 = 1
```

Comment: any whay it should print something like (void*) 0x7fff5fbffa18

Comment: That's strange, try to set bp on line 9 and print `ap`.