# How can we access varargs in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, variadic-functions

When stepping through functions one can end up in a function with a definition like `handle_error (const char *fmt, ...)`.

**How can I access the varargs for constructing a message to be seen in the GDB console?**

Note: I do know from the implementation that it does

```c
    va_list         ap;

    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vfprintf (stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end (ap);
```

So the first though was to just `call` those functions - which isn't possible as `va_start` is a compiler builtin:

```
(gdb) call (void)va_start (ap, fmt)
No symbol "__builtin_va_start" in current context.
(gdb) call (int)vfprintf (stderr, fmt, ap)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6c0ada1 in vfprintf () from target:/usr/lib64/libc.so.6
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
```

To put that into the GDB console I *guess* I'd have to vsprintf to a temporary variable and then use that for output - but as all varargs functions need an initialized va_list...

The GDB is python enabled, but I didn't found any reasonable python handling for C varargs either...

Comment: Print to a large string using `vsprintf` so you can see the message, then send the string to stderr.

Comment: Sounds good, but to do so I need an initialized va_list - and the "regular" way of achieving this is to use `va_start` which cannot be called from GDB...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how that other question's answer applies to this. The only solution given is "step until ´va_start` is executed" (which is explicit NOT what I can do here) and a workaround of effectively using `up` and inspect the 1 to possibly hundred arguments, which then likely comes as function return values that I don't want to execute because of its side effects)?

Comment: If you are on Linux, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073828/1983398) works for you.

Comment: that one only works reliably with a manual `jump` to the instruction that does this (which is only be possible in gdb commands if the source is available/not changed), then do the print, then `jump` to `va_end`, then `jump` back.
It is likely the way I'll go in this specific case but I'd still would see a generic option (possibly calling `va_start` not from the builtin but from libc - if there's any [at least `objdump` showed nothing that looked right]).